# RangeError for list in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, api, dart, flutter-getx

I am working on an app that requires me to display images from an API. It has been working fine till today morning. Today I edited some parts to pass the image to another page and tried running it. It gave the following error:

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

I undid all the changes that I made and am still getting this error.

I understand that the problem is that the list to display the image is empty. But I don't get why it is empty now when it was working fine before.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Before output:

[image: output 1]

The output that I'm getting now:

[image: output 2]

<here it shows "The index is 0" since I added a new container in the column to check the index>

Code to display the images:

```
class wpList extends StatefulWidget {
  const wpList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _wpListState createState() => _wpListState(); 
}


class _wpListState extends State<wpList> {

  final wpControl = Get.put(wpController());
  List data = [];

  List<String> wpUrl= [];
  // List<String> wpUrl1=[];
  bool showing = false;
  var ifliked= 'Like image';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ApiService().getMethod('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=<API KEY>');
     return  ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'The index is $index'
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),

                  Obx(
                    ()=> GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        Get.to(wpView(index: index));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          // color: Colors.grey,
                          //     height: 100,
                              child: Image(
                                image: NetworkImage(wpControl.imgs[index].urls!['regular'])
                              ),
                   
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.teal,
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      elevation: 3,
                      // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
                      minimumSize: Size(300, 40), //////// HERE
                    ),
                    onPressed:(){
                      print("The button $index is pressed");
                      wpControl.sindex.value=index;
                      // setState(() {
                      //   ifliked='Liked';
                      // });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      '$ifliked'
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
  }
}
```

Api service code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

class ApiService{
  Future<dynamic> getMethod(String url) async{
    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    return await dio.get(url,
    options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.json, method: "GET")
    ).then((value){
      log(value.toString());
      return value;
    }); 
  }
}
```

GetX Controller code

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'api_service.dart';
import 'images.dart';

class wpController extends GetxController{
//list of wps
//var wpUrl = List<Imagess>().obs;
  RxList<Imagess> imgs = RxList();

  var sindex = 0.obs;

  getImages() async{
    var response = await 
    ApiService().getMethod('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id= <API KEY>');
    print('response.statusCode');
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      response.data.forEach((elm){
        imgs.add(Imagess.fromJson(elm));
        print('imgs');
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void onInit(){
    getImages();
    super.onInit(); 
  }
}
```

Imagess class:

```
class Imagess{
  String? id;
  String? createdAt;
  String? color;
  Map<String, dynamic>? urls;

  Imagess({
    this.id,
    this.createdAt,
    this.color,
    this.urls
});

  Imagess.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    id = json['id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    color = json['color'];
    urls = json['urls'];
  }
}
```

Debug console output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvblZ.png)

Debug console output 2 :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A3XG.png)

Comment: could you include you code too?

Comment: Please put some code

Comment: please share code.

Comment: please wait..I forgot to add the code and it;s giving some formatting errors now I'll fix that and edit

Comment: could you include `Imagess` class too? @kkridhi

Comment: Can you put your ui code?

Comment: @CCP The ui code for displaying the images is given under the "code to display images " part :)

Comment: @ Salim Murshed @Vishal Zaveri  code added :)

Comment: can you also add sample of your api response? @kkridhi

Comment: 1. In your code list view item count is static which is wrong if its coming from API. 2nd check your urls Map key contains Image url or not.

Comment: @Vishal Zaveri I changed the count from 10 to wpControl.imgs.length . The error went but no images were getting displayed. The url is also correct..the <API KEY> here contains the access key to the API that I used.

Comment: share you response too. because error message that : you added number of data but in actual response doesn't contain that much data.

Comment: @Vishal Zaveri I have added the output of debug console in the question. Also, I notice the exception "type 'list<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' ". Any idea how to rectify this?

Comment: So first check your model map correctly All api data or not then bind with UI. It's type casting issue.

Comment: in your model there is key urls but in your debug console screenshot, I am not getting that key which is set for networkImage widget in UI part.

Comment: @Vishal Zaveri the API has something called "urls" and it has url of the same image of different sizes. 'regular' is one of the size in them. The exclamation mark is added over there since I got an error when I did not add it. So basically it takes the regular sized image out of the urls. The funniest part in this whose thing is that this exact same code ran properly inn the morning but now I'm struggling with it :,(  Should I add the youtube video that I took reference of while doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the everyone! Somehow I made it work correctly! :)

Comment: Just do one thing to replace this urls! ['regular'] with urls? ['regular'] ?? "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9" And check

Comment: Yes also update answer how you fix it which helps others. Happy coding:)

Comment: Even I do not know how, I was running it in debug mode and it kept giving that type casting issue. Then I clicked on resume..and I was just messing around with the debugger. I didn't change anything in the code. Then when I ran in again normally (not in the debug mode) I got the output.  Also, for your other comment, both ! and ? works in that place.

Comment: !  Is hard code practice so instead of that you can go with nullSafty  ?? With default value so app will not crash

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the itemCount with `wpControl.imgs.length` just in case if the response send no data or the image is null the listview.builder will not force to create 10 item and throws an error but it will count how many image data you got from the response

Comment: Hello! I changed it and the red error screen left, but no images are being displayed..this means that nothing is getting added to the list right? In that case, how will I fix it?

Comment: Can you share the log from response data? I need to see the data you get from the api

Comment: How to I get that data?

Comment: Well in this if(response.statusCode == 200){ put print(response.data or response.body)} and share the log in debug console

Comment: That's weird. I'm not able to get the output of the print statement.... I tried using debugPrint() as well. The print statement that I gave under onpressed for go back button is getting displayed tho..

Comment: Since you have this then((value){
      log(value.toString());
      return value;
    });  you should have the log in debug console already

Comment: I'll paste the ss of whatever I get when I hot restart and get to this page in the question.

Comment: Juet find a way to print the data

Comment: I got it to print the response data as u said..output in question

Comment: Hello! thanks for the help! I somehow made it work :)

Comment: Glad to help, give me checklist 

Answer (score 0):

- the url Type maybe is List

```
 var json =
        '{"id":"1","createAt":"20220101","color":"blue","urls":["url1","url2","url3"]}';
 var model = Imagess.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
 print(model.urls);
 // print result : [url1, url2, url3]


class Imagess {
  String? id;
  String? createdAt;
  String? color;
  List<dynamic>? urls;

  Imagess({this.id, this.createdAt, this.color, this.urls});

  Imagess.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    color = json['color'];
    urls = json['urls'];
  }
}
```

- if the url Type  is Map . you can try this code

```
 var json =
        '{"id":"1","createAt":"20220101","color":"blue","urls":{"data":["url1","url2","url3"]}}';
 var model = Imagess.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
 print(model.urls);
 // print result : "data":[url1, url2, url3]

class Imagess {
  String? id;
  String? createdAt;
  String? color;
  UrlModel? urls;

  Imagess({this.id, this.createdAt, this.color, this.urls});

  Imagess.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    color = json['color'];
    urls = UrlModel.fromJson(json['urls']);
  }
}

class UrlModel {
  List<dynamic>? data;
  UrlModel(this.data);
  UrlModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = json['data'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, but somehow I made it work properly just now :)

Comment: @kkridhi good job bro~